# VPN problems: MTU and Don't-Fragment

Tags: nat, mtu, ip-fragmentation

I am setting up a VPN on Ubuntu 14.04LTS which uses IPSEC and performs NAT for clients.  It is basically working - I can connect to it from a clinet (Android device) and browse (for example) www.google.com.

However I cannot browse www.bbc.co.uk.  When I try, my VPN server receives the response from www.bbc.co.uk with the don't-fragment bit set, and discards it.  Wireshark shows many of these:

```
119 7.904053000 212.58.246.95  MY.IP.MY.IP    TCP   1414    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
120 7.904094000 MY.IP.MY.IP    212.58.246.95  ICMP  590     Destination unreachable (Fragmentation needed)
```

By pinging my client from the VPN server, I have ascertained that its MTU is about 1380.  The VPN server's MTU is 1500.

How it this *supposed* to work please?  MTUs can vary, so if the BBC if setting don't-fragment, how is this supposed to be handled please?

I would assume that, if don't-fragment is set, everything should agree on the smallest common MTU.  Can I work out who is misbehaving?

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be the firewall (not the Ubuntu ufw, but the firewall outside my server provided by our IT department) not allowing ICMP packets out.

Once that was enabled, the MTU path discovery (or whatever was going on) started working and all is well.